# How I add an object to an existing array? React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

recently I started to work in a proyect and I notice that I need some way to modify a value without losing my previous state. Basically work with an array. However I don't know how to do that.
Can anyone help me by telling me how can I modify an state (I'm using react hooks by the way...) to add more values to the previous state in an array?

Sorry not posting code or something like that, I don't even know how to write that.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would recommend looking at some tutorials for basic javascript and React if you are unable to provide some starting code for this question. The React tutorial here https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html provides a pretty good starting point as well as answers your question during one of the steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ES6 spread operator to push new object to the existing array.

Adding a new object to an Array:

```
const [todo, setTodo] = useState([{ task: "Todo 1" }]);

const addTodo = () => {
    let newTodoTask = { task: `Task ${todo.length + 1}` };

    setTodo(tasks => [...tasks, { ...newTodoTask }]);
};
```

Modifying an object in an Array:

```
const editTask = (e, taskId = 0) => {
    setTodo(tasks =>
      tasks.map((task, idx) =>
        idx === taskId ? { task: "Edited Todo 1" } : { ...task }
      )
    );
};
```

Deleting an object from an array

```
const deleteTask = (e, taskId = 0) => {
    setTodo(tasks => tasks.filter((task, idx) => idx !== taskId));
};
```

Find the simple working example here.

https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-elgamal-h7fhg?file=/src/App.js:482-593

First, Learn basic ES6 before start working on the project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the previous value returned from the setState to update the existing Array

```
import { useState } from 'react';

    export default function Test() {
      const [state, setstate] = useState([1,2,3,4);
      return <div onClick={() => setstate((prev) => [...prev,99])}>Heyy{state}</div>;
    }
```